# NSDate returning nil in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I am trying to set an `NSDate` from a string. The format of the string looks like this (RFC 2822):

```
Tue, 09 Jun 2015 06:09:38 +0000
```

The code I am using is:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier: @"en_US_POSIX"];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss Z";
NSDate *dateString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:self.time];
```

But `dateString` always returns a nil. `self.time` definitely contains the string for the time.

Comment: This has been asked thousands of times already. Why did you feel it was necessary to create a new question?

Comment: Because I believed it to be out of the ordinary due to not being able to see an obvious error with dateFormat, locale, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I think your self.time is either nil or in some other format. To check your code put string manually and see the result

```
NSString *str = @"Tue, 09 Jun 2015 06:09:38 +0000";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier: @"en_US_POSIX"];
dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss Z";
NSDate *dateString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:str];
NSLog(@"date : %@",dateString);
```

I added a sample it gave me correct result. Try once to debug the value of self.time

Comment: This works great. But `self.time` appears to definitely be set. Very weird...

Comment: Check your value of self.time, there is no error in code. Just debug value of your variables.

Answer (score 1):

If I do this this works absolutely fine

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier: @"en_US_POSIX"];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss Z";
    NSDate *dateString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"Tue, 09 Jun 2015 06:09:38 +0000"];
```

output is : 2015-06-09 06:09:38 +0000

Answer (score 0):

You possibly need to set timezone. 
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone]];